# What happens if printf is not handled

Tags: c, posix

I'm current supporting some legacy software written aeon ago, compiled in gcc 2.95.3. The program is ran in an SBC, occasionally I had to telnet into it to fix things. I notice that when the SBC is running on its own, it display some unexpected behavior e.g. missed executions.

When I do telnet in, slay the process and execute it manually, it stays fine that way. I'm suspecting that this has to do with performing `printf` without a proper terminal/console for it to print on.

If `printf` are not handled, what would be the effect of it?

Comment: Try running the process with stdout redirected to /dev/null ?

Comment: Yes i could, but what happens if printf is not handled, e.g. stdout is the console but there no console

Comment: The purpose of the suggestion was to see whether you still get problems when running with stdout redirected to /dev/null - if it doesn't hang then your hypothesis is probably correct - if it still hangs then the problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the system is trying to print to a hardware serial port (which are really slow) and when you telnet in its replaced by a TCP port instead?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the stdio library you use, most will attempt to write to console anyway, so...

You should redirecting your STDOUT and STDERR to NULL or to a file, this should be quiet easy.
gcc 2.95 was very stable so we can pretty much rule out any problems there.